# Aliases - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Well, I have a doubt. I want to put "aliases" in my commands in discord.js, but I am stuck without knowing what to do. Help me if something is missing, please.

This is my `index.js` code

```
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands')

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`)
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command)
    }
}
```

code 2:

```
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(process.env.PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    const args = message.content.slice(process.env.PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    try {
        bot.commands.get(command).execute(bot, message, args)
    } catch (e) {
        message.channel.send('Utilize ``' + `${process.env.PREFIX}` + 'help`` para ver meus comandos.')
            .then(message => setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000))
    } 
});
```

This is the part of the code of the commands, I put the aliases there but it is not working.

```
const execute = async (bot, message, args) => {
//code
};

module.exports ={
    name: "ban",
    aliases: ['b', 'banir'],
    execute,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `client.commands` for a module that *either has the name of* `args.shift().toLowerCase()` or *it's* `aliases` *array contains said argument*

```
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(process.env.PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
    const args = message.content.slice(process.env.PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    // Aliases Implementing starts here
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
    if (!command) return;

    try {
        bot.commands.get(command).execute(bot, message, args)
    } catch (e) {
        message.channel.send('Utilize ``' + `${process.env.PREFIX}` + 'help`` para ver meus comandos.')
            .then(message => setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000))
    } 
});
```

Here's an official aliases guide by [Discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#command-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Simply register your aliases for a command along with the command name, like this:

```
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`)
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command)
        // Register aliases
        for (let alias of command.aliases) {
            bot.commands.set(alias, command)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution, this will result in multiple Collection entries which all point to the same command.